# Finding lines by keywords and getting the value of said line in python

Tags: python

i am quite new to Python and i would like to ask the following:

Let's say for example i have the following .txt file:

```
USERNAME -- example.name

SERVER -- server01

COMPUTERNAME -- computer01
```

I would like to search through this document for the 3 keywords: `USERNAME`, `SERVER` and `COMPUTERNAME` and when I find these, I would like to extract their values, a.i `"example.name", "server01" and "computer01"` respectively for each line.

Is this possible? I have already tried for looking by line numbers, but I would much prefer searching by keywords instead.

**Question 2**: Somewhere in this .txt file exists a line with the keyword `Adresses:` which has multiple values but listed in different lines, like such:

```
Adresses:  

         6001:8000:1080:142::12

         8002:2013:2380:110::53

         9007:2013:2380:117::80

         .

         .
```

Would there be any way to get all of the listed addresses as a result, not just the first one? The number of said addresses is dynamic, so it may change in the future.

To this i have honestly no idea how to begin. I appreciate any kind of hints or pointing me in the right direction.

Thank you very much for your time and attention!

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
with open("filename.txt") as f:
  for x in f:
    a = x.split(" -- ")
    print(a[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

If line with given value always starts with keyword you can try something like this

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
  for line in file:
    if line.startswith('keyword'):
      keyword, value = line.split(' -- ')
```

and to gather all the addresses i'd initiate list of addresses beforehand, then add line

```
addresses.append(value)
```

inside of if statement

Answer (score 0):

Your best friend for this kind of task will be [`str.split` function](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/split.html). You can put your data in a `dict` which will map keywords to values :

```py
data = {}                                     # Create a new dict
with open('data.txt') as file:                # Open the file containing the data
  lines = file.read().split('\n')             # Split the file in lines
  for line in lines:                          # For each line
    keyword, value = line.split(' -- ')       # Extract keyword and value
    data[keyword] = value                     # Put in the dict
```

Then, you can access your values with `data['USERNAME']` for example. This method will work on any document containing a key-value association on each line (even if you have more than 3 keywords). However, it will **not work** if the same text file contains the addresses in the format you mentionned.

If you want to include the addresses in the same file, you'll need to adapt the code. You can for example check if `splitted_line` contains two elements (= key-value on the same line, like `USERNAME`) or only one (= key-value on multiple lines, like `Addresses:`). Then, you can store in a list all the different addresses, and bound this list to the `data` dict. It's not a problem to have a dict in the form :

```py
{
'USERNAME': 'example.name',
'Addresses': ['6001:8000:1080:142::12', '8002:2013:2380:110::53']
}
```